# use expect to enter password when need sudo in script

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, expect

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and installed expect. I am trying to write a script to enter password when it prompted.
**UPDATED Code:**

```
  #!/usr/bin/expect -d
  set timeout 20

  set pw odroid
  spawn sudo apt-get update

  expect {\[sudo]\ password for odroid: }
  send "$pw\r"

  close
```

Any suggestions? thx

**UPDATE Errors:**

```
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "\[sudo]\ password for odroid: "? no
[sudo] password for odroid: 
expect: does "[sudo] password for odroid: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "\[sudo]\ password for odroid: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "[sudo] password for odroid: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "[sudo] password for odroid: "
send: sending "odroid\r" to { exp4 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many quotes. Choose one of:

```
expect {\[sudo\] password for odroid: }
expect "\\\[sudo\\\] password for odroid: "
```

Clearly the first option is better.

Lots of escaping is necessary because 1) square brackets are special in a glob pattern, and 2) square brackets are special Tcl syntax (command substitution) in double quotes but not in curly braces.

Comment: Hi glenn, I changed as you said and this problems fixed. but still don't work. I add new output in my problem. please give me some suggestions. thx

Comment: Did you look at that debug output? The pattern did match and the password was sent. Whatever the problem is, it's not in what you've shown us.

Comment: but the updated informations are the output I have. How can I display the problem I have besides include `-d` in the script. thx

Answer (score 2):

A more generic way of solving your issue would be matching on **assword**

```
expect "*?assword*"
```

This allows for a more generic script where the **username** is irrelevant.

I also had the following issue with the snippet below. Basically **$pw** gets interpreted by the shell and needs to be set **outside** the expect TCL code.

```
pw="Password1234"

expect -f - <<-EOF
  set timeout 10

  spawn sudo -k
  spawn sudo mysql_secure_installation
  expect "*?assword*"
  send -- "$pw\r"
  expect eof
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with this, it should work fine.

`expect "\[sudo\] password for odroid:\r"`