# How to provide password when prompted in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am writing the shell script to automate few tasks. I am logging into the remote server and installing a few packages.
But to install I need to get the root access.
I am able to login using my credentials with ssh keys.
Once I login I need to switch to root, and then it asks for the password. I tried using echo it still asks for the password.

```
SCRIPT="pwd; ls; echo 'rootpass' | su -; cd ~; pwd; yum -y install <package>"
```

How can I pass the password on prompt.
I need to maintain the same session, so not sure spawn/expect/send is gonna work.

UPDATE:
I tried using printf 'rootpass' | ./script.sh, but it is not working.

Comment: Think about installing packages using sudo

Comment: users can not be a part of sudoer's so we can not add that. we want to read it from a variable and pass it on when prompted.

Comment: Typically, you configure `sudo` so that the user can run `yum -y install` (and more importantly, no or few other commands) without a password.

Comment: Look into `expect` instead.

Comment: Security wise, this is bad, very bad.  It means you will have to store the root password somewhere on the origin server to send it to the remote server.  `sudo` is the way to go since it allows you to limit what commands can be used as well as protect the root password.

Comment: Your current script would execute `cd ~` etc only after `su` finishes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc

Comment: Saving a script in a variable is almost never the correct thing to do; see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

As commented, and [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961331/6309), [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) is a better option.

```sh
pw="Password1234"

expect -f - <<-EOF
  set timeout 10

  spawn sudo yum -y install <package>
  expect "*?assword*"
  send -- "$pw\r"
  expect eof
EOF
```

However, It is best for any script to *not* include the password itself directly, but rather to fetch that password from an external source, preferable a vault.
Typically, such a script would be run by a tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com), using [`ansible-community/ansible-vault`](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-vault). Only Ansible would have the Vault password, Valut which in turn would have the sudo password.